# How can I compare the latency of searching over a entire network against LDAP

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, ldap, windows-authentication

Currently the existing application that I work in my day job has Windows Authentication where they use LDAP. LDAP path is formed using

```
LDAPPath = "LDAP://dc=xyz,dc=xyz,dc=xyz,dc=xyz"
FullCommand = "Select ADsPath from '" & LDAPPath & "' where sAMAccountName='abcd'"
```

Instead of this I want to use getobject("WinNT://" & userid). I would like to know how can I check if by using this method I would have to suffer latency in my program. Using WinNT would make it domain agnostic, but do we have performance penalty is what I need to look at.
After performing getobject() I iterate through all the groups and check if the group I need is present or not.

Answer (score 0):

> After performing getobject() I iterate through all the groups and
>   check if the group I need is present or not.

Why? Why not just execute an LDAP search for the group you are looking for? This is *far* more efficient as it executes at the server and doesn't require shipping on average N/2 groups over the wire.

Comment: The LDAP Query for a domain we are switching too ain't working. It's not working specifically because of IIS Integrated Windows Authentication.

Comment: @gizgok that doesn't actually answer my question. It's quite likely that your suboptimal 'solution' is actually making the situation worse, as you are forcing the server and the network to work much harder.